# CSV data exported/copied to HDFS going in weird format

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop2

I am using a spark job for reading csv file data from a stating area and coping that data into HDFS using following code line:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WCRemoteReadHDFSWrite").set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "true");
          
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.textFile(source)

rdd.saveAsTextFile(destination)
```

csv file is having data in following format:

> CTId,C3UID,region,product,KeyWord
>
> 1,1004634181441040000,East,Mobile,NA
>
> 2,1004634181441040000,West,Tablet,NA

whereas when data goes into HDFS it goes in following format:

> CTId,C3UID,region,product,KeyWord
>
> 1,1.00463E+18,East,Mobile,NA
>
> 2,1.00463E+18,West,Tablet,NA

I am not able to find any valid reason behind this.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Bhupesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that because your C3UID is a large number, it gets parsed as Double and then is saved in standard Double notation. You need to fix the schema, and make sure you read the second column either as Long, BigDecimal or String, then there will be no change in String-representation.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Rick Moritz when you say that I should fix my schema, does that mean I should use Spark Dataframe API for reading data from shared location and writing that data into HDFS?

Comment: @ChauhanB : Not necessarily - but it may help. A good starting point would be to check the types that are in the RDD - the detection of Double may already happen in sc.textFile, or in the save step. If you really want to just copy the data, also consider using the HDFS-API, instead of/inside Spark. If you want to re-use the data in the follow-up processing, using Spark is a better option -- for this kind o data, the DataFrame API is more suitable, so I would recommend that.

Comment: I want to go for Spark API as I want to do some kind of data sanity, data cleansing on top of the row data before saving it to HDFS. I have explored other tools as well like Apache Nifi but I want to avoid cost of having extra cluster for Apache Nifi. I want to leverage my existing spark and HDFS cluster where my main application would be running after loading data in HDFS. Do you see it as a good approach? Do you feel using Spark for data on-boarding is a good idea [where I would be doing data cleansing in between], before saving data to HDFS?

Comment: @ChauhanB Yes, I would recommend it, but I would also recommend using DataFrames or DataSets in that situation, since those APIs are much more convenient to work with, and designed with those tasks in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes your CSV file could also be the culprit. Do NOT open CSV file in excel as excel could convert those big numeric values into exponential format and hence once you use spark job for importing data into hdfs, it goes as it is in string format.

Hence be very sure that your data in CSV should never be opened in excel before importing to hdfs using spark job. If you really want to see the content of your excel use either notepad++ or any other text editor tool